# DRF nested serializers - Filtering data on child serializers

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use nested serializer. How do I use the root serializer to filter data on the grandchild serializer?

School and Program have a many to many relationship So that any school can subscribe to any program. Each school has classes and those classes are part of a program, that's why PClass has foreign keys to both School and program.

When I call my api .../api/school/1 I want to get all the programs that school subscribes to and which classes are available in each program (in that school)

```py
class School(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)

class Program(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,default='',blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, blank=True, null=True, related_name="programs")

class PClass(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,default='',blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, related_name="classes")
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name="classes")
```

and the following serializers:

```py
class SchoolSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer):
    programs = ProgramSerializer(source='get_programas',many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = '__all__'
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }

class PClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ('name','slug')

class ProgramSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    school = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=School.objects.all(),
                                            slug_field='name',
                                            required=False)
    classes = PClassSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Program
        exclude = ('id',)
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

is this possible? or is it a problem with the way I set up my models?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's 2 ways I know how to do this. The first is you're pretty close already
EDIT: Noticed you're using related names. I've updated the answer for that

```
class SchoolSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer):
    programas = ProgramSerializer(source='programs',many=True,read_only=True)
```

For more complex filtering the best way is to use a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) Field. Here's an example.

You'll probably want to also do some pre-fetches in your view to get the queryset to minimize the # of queries.

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    programas = SerializerMethodField(source='get_programas',many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Unidade
        fields = '__all__'
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }

    def get_programas(self, obj):
        # You can do more complex filtering stuff here.
        return ProgramaSerializer(obj.programs.all(), many=True, read_only=True).data
```

To get the PClasses you'll just need to filter your queryset with

```
program.classes.filter(school=program.school)
```

Full example for ProgramSerializer is

```
class ProgramSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    classes = SerializerMethodField(source='get_classes', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Program

    def get_classes(self, obj):
        return PClassSerializer(obj.classes.filter(school=obj.school), many=True, read_only=True).data
```

**EDIT 10 or so:**

Since you have changed the program -> School from foreignkey to ManyToMany, this changes everything.

For the schoolserializer, you need to use a SerializerMethodField. This way you can pass in extra [context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to your nested serializer.

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    classes = SerializerMethodField(source='get_programs')
    class Meta:
        model = School

    def get_programs(self, obj):
        return ProgramSerializer(obj.program_set.all(), many=True, read_only=True, context={ "school": obj }).data

class ProgramSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    classes = SerializerMethodField(source='get_classes', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Program

    def get_classes(self, obj):
        return PClassSerializer(obj.classes.filter(school=self.context["school"]), many=True, read_only=True).data
```

Comment: How do I get PClassSerializer to display only the classes on the School being serialized on SchoolSerializer?

Comment: Just added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: but program.school will return a list with all the schools enrolled in this program, won't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: and where should I put the
 
     program.pclass_set.filter(school=program.school)

I am sorry, need more details on this... after spending the afternoon researching I am a bit lost...

Comment: Hope this works now! Let me know if you have any more questions and I will add more to the answer.

Comment: I can't filter yet, as obj.school seems to be a  'ManyRelatedManager'. I am getting the school manager from the program serializer and not the Grandparent school

Comment: A general tip for Django programming is to avoid using related_name unless necessary, since it's easier for others to just use the default _set syntax. Just noticed all your related_names and have updated the answer to use the correct references

Comment: thanks, sorry about that. Still getting the same error
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'

I think it's related to obj.school referring to the Program.school attribute and not the School object

Comment: can you put a print() statement in get_classes and tell me what type obj is?

Comment: couldn't print but I could get from an error log from sentry: <Program: test>

Comment: Not sure if these are fixed already, but in your original post, you had 

SchoolSerializer with class Unidade, and PClassSerializer with class Turma. Also make sure that Program is using a foreign key to school, and not a manytomanyfield.  

If you use my example I don't see any reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I translated the names to simplify things and forgot to change that. Already edited it. Program has a many to many relationship to School, as schools subscribe to programs. I can't change it to a foreign key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149855/discussion-between-jonzlin95-and-jlugao).

Comment: I am accepting this as answer. Please note that after the return Serializer() there is a .data missing. as in return.ProgramSerializer(...).data. Without this it won't work. Thank you for your help